# How to convert box-shadow, to a linear-gradient?

Tags: css, linear-gradients

How would I convert this code to a linear-gradient?

https://jsfiddle.net/bufpark1/

```
.box {
  box-shadow:
    0 0 0 5px teal,
    0 0 0 10px black,
    0 0 0 15px orange,
    0 0 0 20px black,
    0 0 0 25px teal,
    0 0 0 30px black,
    0 0 0 35px orange,
    0 0 0 40px black,
    0 0 0 45px teal,
    0 0 0 50px black,
    0 0 0 55px orange,
    0 0 0 60px black,
    0 0 0 65px teal,
    0 0 0 70px black,
    0 0 0 75px orange,
    0 0 0 80px black,
    0 0 0 85px teal;
}
```

[image]

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #333333;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  box-shadow:
    0 0 0 5px teal,
    0 0 0 10px black,
    0 0 0 15px orange,
    0 0 0 20px black,
    0 0 0 25px teal,
    0 0 0 30px black,
    0 0 0 35px orange,
    0 0 0 40px black,
    0 0 0 45px teal,
    0 0 0 50px black,
    0 0 0 55px orange,
    0 0 0 60px black,
    0 0 0 65px teal,
    0 0 0 70px black,
    0 0 0 75px orange,
    0 0 0 80px black,
    0 0 0 85px teal;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: do you need the exact box size for the linear gradient too?

Comment: 170 x 170. yes.

Comment: I want to use a gradient instead of a box-shadow. That's what I want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`linear-gradient` alone cannot do it. you need more properties.

Here is my idea using `clip-path`

```css
body {
  background: #333333;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin:0;
}

.box {
  width:225px;
  background:repeating-linear-gradient(teal 0 5px,black 0 10px,orange 0 15px,black 0 20px);
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  padding-top:100%;
  background:inherit;
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,100% 0,0 100%,100% 100%);
  transform:rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Also like below:

```css
body {
  background: #333333;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin:0;
}

.box {
  width:220px; /* adjust this value */
  --coloration:teal 0 5px,black 0 10px,orange 0 15px,black 0 20px;
  background:
     repeating-linear-gradient(0deg,  var(--coloration)) top,
     repeating-linear-gradient(180deg,var(--coloration)) bottom;
  background-size:100% 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  padding-top:100%;
  background:inherit;
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,100% 0,0 100%,100% 100%);
  transform:rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: "linear-gradient alone cannot do it alone." Are you 100% sure about that?

Comment: @csshtmljavascript14578 yes because your image is not a *linear* gradient, you need more than a gradient but I think I cannot convince you like your previous question ...

Comment: I did it here. https://jsfiddle.net/5h8mLy90/ Is that not it?

Comment: @csshtmljavascript14578 that's not *a linear-gradient* but multiple linear-gradient stacked on the top of each other. I guess my solution that uses no more than 2 gradients is more efficient and also scalable

Comment: Can the one I made use repeating gradient to lessen the amount of code?

Comment: I asked it here, maybe it's not able to be done, or I'm doing it wrong. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68677541/how-to-use-repeating-gradient-to-create-a-square

Comment: @csshtmljavascript14578 I already gave you the repeating-gradient solution .. I don't see whay re-asking the same quesiton ...

Comment: This is what yours looks like at 170 x 170 https://jsfiddle.net/ugpdr5b0/ It does not look like this: https://i.imgur.com/SooSwAV.png

Comment: Can I add repeating gradient to the stacked gradient code I made? https://jsfiddle.net/5h8mLy90/

Comment: @csshtmljavascript14578 I have added two snippet, use the second one

Comment: How would I be able to get it to work using your first code? https://jsfiddle.net/qhnax5t4/ What would need to be adjusted in it?

Comment: I fixed it here https://jsfiddle.net/0cdyj9g1/ background-size: 100% 50%;

Comment: The code is not able to use background-repeat: no-repeat; How come? Look what happens when it is added. https://jsfiddle.net/9czqxLh6/